# std::bitset::at() disappear in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I used to use `bitset::at(x)`, the robust runtime checked version to check if any bit from a `bitset<>` is set. But in VS2015, I am getting this error:

```
std::bitset<6> bTestFlag;
int b = bTestFlag.at(3); // Error C2039 'at': is not a member of 'std::bitset<6>'
```

Why did it disappear in VS2015?

Comment: Because it is not standard compliant: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: Adding things to `std::` not defined by the standard is non-conforming behaviour. *Using* such features is also non-conforming behaviour. Microsoft fixed their side, now you have to fix yours. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Is it actually non-conformance for an implementation to *add* stuff to `std`? I can't seem to find this spelled out in the standard anywhere.

Comment: @Angew: {stuff deleted} On second thought, the term is probably "reserved to the implementation", which means the OP mustn't, but Microsoft -- "the implementation" in this case -- certainly can... I don't know, really.

Comment: @DevSolar That was my feeling as well. I would think the implementation can add (and even document) extra stuff, as long as its presence does not cause strictly-by-the-standard programs to misexecute (such as pick up an unexpected overload).

Comment: @Angew: one way or the other, things like this result in non-portable code, and the programmer may not even realize it until it's too late.

Comment: @Angew: Found it, in namespace.std -- behaviour *of a program* is undefined if it adds to namespace `std`. So the library is free to add extensions. (Really bad practice, though. As if MS ever cared.)

Comment: An implementation certainly can add stuff to std. It might even change standard-defined functions and templates by, for example, adding defaulted arguments - as long as code written in accordance with standard compiles and behaves as specified in standard.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for [`std::bitset::test()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/test). That is the correct member function that checks a bit, but throws `std::out_of_range` if the provided index isn't a valid position. There was never an `at()`.

Comment: Yes that ist the same.
I have looked in VS9, VS10, VS12, VS14, bitset::at() was until VS12 and has definively gone in VS14. So I have now to fix my code as @DevSolar says.. :(